# Angular Nativescript can't navigate in lazy module

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular-router

Template I used : 
[Nativescript-Tabs-Template](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-tab-navigation-ng)

**When I try to navigate to sibling component (both are in one lazy module) with:**

```
 showItem() {
    this.routerExtensions.navigate(["details/"]);
}
```

(also done this - not sure if this is ok ) :

```
this.routerExtensions.navigate(["details", { outlets: { searchTab: ['details'] } }]);
```

**I get the error :**

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'details'

***But when I navigate with nsRouterLink it works: ***

```
<Label text="this works" [nsRouterLink]="['/details']></Label>
```

App.components.html Tab :

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <page-router-outlet
    *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
    name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

Router.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/(homeTab:home/default//browseTab:browse/default//searchTab:search/default)",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
    {
        path: "search",
        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: "~/app/search/search.module#SearchModule",
        outlet: "searchTab"
    }
]
```

Search.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { SearchRoutingModule } from "./search-routing.module";
import { SearchComponent } from "./search.component";
import { NgShadowModule } from 'nativescript-ng-shadow';
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { LabelMaxLinesDirective } from "../directives/label-max-lines.directive";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item-detail/item-detail.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        SearchRoutingModule,
        NgShadowModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchComponent,
        LabelMaxLinesDirective,
        ItemDetailComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class SearchModule { }
```

Search.router.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { SearchComponent } from "./search.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item-detail/item-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "default", component: SearchComponent },
    { path: "details", component: ItemDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class SearchRoutingModule { }
```

**What Am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: try  `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["./details"]);`

Comment: Tryed, not working

Comment: Maybe somehow I need to specify the outlet when I am navigating ?

Comment: `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["details/"]);` should be `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/details"]);`

Comment: also, dont put anything outside the `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`, it should be the outermost tag

Comment: Not working with /details - same error

Comment: You should load detail page with the outlet name. The route will look similar to `/(homeTab:home/default//browseTab:browse/default//searchTab:search/default)` but instead of default, you are going to load detail page.

Comment: this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/searchTab:search/details"]); - you mean ?

Comment: swap all of your `<page-router-outlet>`'s to `<router-outlet>`'s, expect the one in the app.component.html file

Comment: I don't think thats a good idea because I use this template from nativescript angular team. Also tryied - error : Changing the view of an already loaded TabViewItem is not currently supported

Comment: it is a good idea, `<page-router-outlet>` is designed to b the top level tag, with nothing outside it because of how it works, if you nest them, you get horrible and easily avoidable errors

Comment: Then why angular-nativescript team built it for the default template ?

Comment: i dont know, but it honestly isnt advised to nest them

Comment: Could you please answer with more details - how to change that it would work ? Because if I change just from page router outlet to router outlet , it won't work.

Comment: theres a high chance it will, like i said, it fixes a lot of errors by using them correctly

Comment: It says error for me : Changing the view of an already loaded TabViewItem is not currently supported

Comment: what version of nativescript are you using? im pretty sure the router in a tabview is a very new feature

Comment: this is the template i used : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-tab-navigation-ng

Comment: Your current version is 5.2.3 and the latest available version is 5.2.4

Comment: not a clue how that app works because it literally cant work, you cant have the tabview as the outermost tag, it needs the `<page-router-outlet>` to render the page. in nativescript, the `<page-router-outlet>` is just about equivalent to an android activity, so it has to be the outer tag

Comment: Everything works with lazy loaded modules - everything works with [nsRouterOutlet] , just not wiith routerExtensions. I don't realy think that they could do a very bad app template.

Comment: the documentation is typically always either out of date or incomplete, and i have known most of the template that i have tried to error when trying to use them

Comment: Let's hope that there will be a second or a third opinion about this template.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/search/details"]);`
include the parent route path before its child path

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript Tabs Template is no longer recommended. Use this tutorial from NativeScript
Blog:

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation

And its example in GitHub:

https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng

In this example each tab has its own navigation tree and you can go back and forward independently (Like Facebook app does).
Inside tabs every navigation is relative, so don't use something like `['/foo']`.

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: RouterExtensions
) { }

goForward() {
  const navigation: ExtendedNavigationExtras = {
    relativeTo: this.route,
    transition: {
    name: 'slide'
    }
  };

  this.router.navigate(['../foo'], navigation);
}

goBack() {
  this.router.back();
}
```