# Nativescript right tabsview architecture?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular-router

I started the app with angular-nativescript lazy "tabs" [template](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-tab-navigation-ng). Later I faced the problem that I **can't move between pages** with "`router`" or "`routerExtensions`". Only with `[nsRouterLink]` which is written in HTML. Also the problem is I can't use one page which is shared between different pages.

**Is this template is right way to use tabs in nativescript ?**

app.component :

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
        name="browseTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Search', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

Comment: Yes the template works. Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241335/angular-nativescript-cant-navigate-in-lazy-module?noredirect=1#comment97217244_55241335 got no answers right here

Comment: There was no direct answer but you hot the hint already, you should supply the route for each outlets when you have multiple. If you are looking for detailed one, you might want to share a complete Playground for the use case.

Comment: You can use that template and download it. My architecture is the same - for a detailed answer.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WvQnzu&v=19 is this the right way to do ?